# How can I use lowercase letters only validation pattern

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, validation, email-address

I have email pattern validation. I'm using now this pattern

```
$scope.emailpattern=/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
```

Its applicable `Uppercase` and `LowerCase` letters I want only lower case letters.

Answer (score 2):

try this, it's working for me:

```
var emailRegex = /^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/;
```

Comment: But its not working (.) decimals example like ths kondaldurgam.Johnny231@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

If you want the same pattern but for it to not apply to upper case letters, remove the `A-Z` qualifiers so it looks like this:

```
$scope.emailpattern=/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,}))$/;
```